# Identify Sequence and Act by it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

I have a table with many kinds of sequences. For example :

```
ID  G_Ind Amount  rnk_date
1    1    50      1
1    0   100      2 
1    0    50      3 
1    1   100      4
2    0    50      1
2    1   100      2
2    0    50      3
2    1   100      4
3    0    50      1
3    1   100      2
3    1    50      3
3    0   100      4
4    0   100      1
4    1    50      2
4    1   100      3
5    1    50      1
5    1   100      2
5    0    50      3
5    0   100      4
5    1    50      5
5    1   100      6

And my desired output is : 


   ID  G_ind Amount  rnk_date rank_date_internal_forIndG Amount_To_Take  
    1    1    50      1                      1               0            
    1    0   100      2                     NULL            100
    1    0    50      3                     NULL            50
    1    1   100      4                      2              100
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    2    0    50      1                      NULL           50
    2    1   100      2                       1             0
    2    0    50      3                      NULL           50
    2    1   100      4                       2             100
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    3    0    50      1                     NULL            50
    3    1   100      2                       1              0
    3    1    50      3                       2             50
    3    0   100      4                     NULL            100
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    4    0   100      1                     NULL            100
    4    1    50      2                      1              0
    4    1   100      3                      2              100
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    5    1    50      1                      1              0
    5    1   100      2                      2              0
    5    0    50      3                      NULL           50
    5    0   100      4                      NULL           100
    5    1    50      5                      3              50
    5    1   100      6                      4              100
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've already built the the four first columns and I'm Trying to calculate the " Amount_To_Take".

hope it's not too complicated to explain but I will try:

In Id = 1 the Amount_To_Take is 0 where G_Ind = 1 for the first time.

*In all cases without exception when G_Ind=1 for the first time (according to internal rank_date I've added -  rank_date_internal_forIndG) We are going to put zero in the  Amount_To_Take.

My problem is when the rank_date_internal_forIndG = 2. In Id - 1,2,3,4 we are going to sum the amout and put it on the  Amount_To_Take so it simple :

```
case when rank_date_internal_forIndG = 2 and G_Ind = 1 then 0
```

but in case when ID is 5 we aren't because it  isn't the last one.

Those are currently all my options so don't bother think of the rest of the combinations. happy to here suggestions how to cope with this (case when ID = 5 and the diffrence between the other two four)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you can get the fifth column as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when g_ind = 1
             then row_number() over (partition by id, g_ind order by rnkdate)
        end) as rank_date_internal_forIndG
from t;
```

You can get the last column as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rank_date_internal_forIndG = 1 then 0
             else amount
        end) as amount_to_take
from (select t.*,
             (case when g_ind = 1
                   then row_number() over (partition by id, g_ind order by rnkdate)
              end) as rank_date_internal_forIndG
      from t
     ) t;
```